# CSS - Method to reduce text in filter so it doesn't take up that much screen space

Tags: html, css

I've had issues like this before and used `word-wrap: break-word;` to fix it, however I've been trying to work on the filter but it doesn't seem to be working. Is there any method in CSS or HTML that could prevent this from happening:

[image]

CCS code:

```
.form-control, select {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #858585;
    background-color: #fbfbfb;
    border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    max-width: 100%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: If you could add more code it would be helpfull

Comment: There's no css to limit the width there, the text itself will limit too but will not add an ellipses even with text-overflow: ellipses hence one of the reasons people use a fake select over the real one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the container node does have some width specified since the select is `max-width:100%` or give a `max-width` in an absolute unit to the select you want to apply the restriction.

```css
.form-control,
select {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #858585;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  max-width: 100%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

select.restricted-size{
  max-width:300px;
}
```

```html
<select class="restricted-size">
  <option>short</option>
  <option>long_dfsjhksjhdfkjsdhfkjshdkjsdhksdhkjsfhksjdhkdhjdskjhdskjdhkjsdf</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hey, the method worked but having one issue, the width is affecting other drop downs. Is there any possibility to just have the max width for this specific filter?  Just new to CSS so not to sure how it works.

Comment: @qwrqwrqrq updated answer. The idea is you can pass a class to that specific `select` element which will set a specific `max-width` for it only.

Answer (score 0):

You need to limit the width of the input either directly or by limiting the width of the parent and then use something like the following to cut off any overflow.

```
white-space: nowrap;      /*keep text on one line */
overflow: hidden;         /*prevent text from being shown outside the border */
text-overflow: ellipsis;  /*cut off text with an ellipsis*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use css ellipsis, define a maximum width for your element, and then add the ellipsis property this will add dots at the end of your element..
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/

```css
h1 {
  max-width: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  margin: 0;
  background: white;
  resize: horizontal;
}
#specificElement {
  width: 200px
}
```

```html
<h1 id="specificElement">
  This little piggy went to market and this little piggy stayed home.
</h1>
```

Comment: Hey, method worked but having one issue, the width is affective everything. Is there any possible to just have the max width for this specific filter?

Answer (score 0):

firtsly, specify your div's width, ex:

```
myDiv {
     width: 100px;
     }
```

then,

```
.form-control, select{
          max-width: 100%;
          }
```

if it doesn't work then try this:

```
.form-control, select {
      word-wrap: break-all;
         }
```

because not all browsers support break-word